# Footer overlapping body content even with clearfix

Tags: html, css, css-position, clearfix

I cannot figure out why my footer will not appear after the content of my page, but instead is overlapping the content.  I have added a clearfix after my floated elements but the footer still overlaps my 'slides.'  You can see what I'm talking about in my fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/4x1n01yo/.  Any help is much appreciated.

I have tried adding:

```
.slides-container{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

But this only partially fixes the problem by moving the footer about halfway down the page.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's because `.slides` has a height of `0`. It has a height of `0` because all its children are absolutely positioned. For a quick fix you could add the following CSS:

```css
.slides {
    height: 899px;
}
```

But this won't help much if all your slides are different heights.

Comment: By simply removing the absolute positioning of .slides the footer should jump down where it should be

Comment: @Nate Whittaker thanks for the help!  I made that update and it definitely helped but the 'gift-card-tagline' p tag is still being overlapped.  I don't understand why it's not being included with the rest of the container.

Comment: @JordanBarber, the height of `.slides` just needs to match the height of its visible child element(s). I edited the answer to a height that should account for the height of the `p.gift-card-tagline` element.